# What can we say about monotonicity at $f'$ over $I$?

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:** Let $f:I\subset  \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and suppose that $[(f'(x))^{2}]'\leqslant 0$ for all $x\in I$. So, what can we say about monotonicity at $f'$ over $I$?

I know that since that $[(f'(x))^{2}]'\leqslant 0$ for all $x\in I$ so we have the function  $(f')^{2}$ is non increasing function on $I$ and since that $(f')^{2}$ is non-increasing function on $I$ so by definition
$$\forall a,b\in I: a\leqslant b \implies (f'(b))^{2}\leqslant (f'(a))^{2}.$$
But, since that $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is increasing mapping so
$$f'(b)\leqslant f'(a).$$
Therefore, $$\forall a,b\in I: a\leqslant b \implies f'(b)\leqslant f'(a)$$
and then by definition $f'$ is non-increasing function on $I$.

Is it correct? any suggestion? If my proof is correct, is there a stronger result? That is, can I weaken the hypotheses and still maintain the result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your argument for deducing $f'(b)\leq f'(a)$ only works for $f'(a),f'(b)\geq 0$, since the mapping $x\mapsto\sqrt x$ is only defined for $x\geq 0$. Consider $f:[-1,0]\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto\pm x^2$, then $[(f'(x))^2]'=8x\leq 0$ for all $x\in[-1,0]$ for both functions, but $f'(x)=\pm2x$ and one is increasing and one is decreasing.

Comment: Thank you so much, but if $(f(x+h)-f(x))^{2})^{'}\leqslant 0$ can we conclude that $f$ is non increasing on $[0,\infty)$ for example? I was thinking about that originally.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but one observation is that $[(f'(x))^2]' = 2f'(x) f''(x)$, so your condition is equivalent to $f'(x) f''(x) \leq 0$, i.e. at each point the first and second derivatives have opposite signs (or one of them is zero).

Comment: Btw, don't you need $f$ to be twice-differentiable in order for $[(f'(x))^2]'$ to be defined?

Comment: @Bungo Yes I also think that. Thank you.

Comment: Technically, you don't need $f$ to be twice-differentiable in order for $(f')^2$ to be differentiable. Take $f$ to be an antiderivative of $|x|$, then $f'(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable in $0$, but $(f'(x))^2=x^2$ is.

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht Fair point! My concern was that once-differentiability of $f$ is not sufficient in general. Twice-differentiability is sufficient, but as you show, it's not necessary. I guess the most reasonable assumption is $f$ is sufficiently well-behaved that $[(f'(x))^2]'$ exists, and leave it at that. :D

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht: I wonder if we can conclude that $f'$ is at least continuous. By Darboux's theorem, we already know that $f'$ must have the intermediate value property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is not correct. The mistake is pointed out in the comments. Your argument would work if you already knew $f' \geqslant 0$ to begin with.

**Example.** Consider $I = \Bbb R$ and $f(x) = e^{-x}$.
Then, $f'(x) = -e^{-x}$. This is an **increasing** function. However, it does satisfy your hypothesis since $[(f'(x))^2]' = [e^{-2x}]' = -2e^{-2x} \leqslant 0$.

---

In fact, if you know for a fact that $f' \leqslant 0$, then your hypothesis implies that $f'$ is going to be increasing.

In both the cases, the argument to use is the following: The function $x \mapsto x^2$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$ and decreasing on $(-\infty, 0]$.

---

So now, we are left with the case that $f'$ takes both positive and negative values. We show that this cannot happen. (I am going to be assuming that $f'$ is continuous.)

Assume that $a, b \in I$ are such that $$a < b \quad\text{and}\quad f'(a) < 0 < f'(b).$$
(The case $f'(b) < 0 < f'(a)$ is similar.)

Now, by the intermediate value property, there exists $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f'(c) = 0$. Now, since $(f')^2$ is non-increasing and non-negative, this forces that $f'(b) = 0$. A contradiction.

---

**Conclusion.** If $[(f')^2]' \leqslant 0$ <strike>(and if $f'$ is continuous)</strike>$^\sharp$, then $f'$ is of one sign.
If $f' \leqslant 0$, then $f'$ is increasing. If $f' \geqslant 0$, then $f'$ is decreasing.

---

$^\sharp$ **Edit:** I realise this now that I don't require $f'$ to be continuous. The only thing that I used was that $f'$ has the intermediate value property. But this is always true! See [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What can we say about the monoticity of $|f'|$ on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: @mathproof: $|f'|$ is going to be decreasing. Indeed, if $x^2 < y^2$, then $|x| < |y|$. (I assume that you mean $I$ instead of $[0, \infty)$.)

Comment: Thank you! I think that now I can correct my argument. Yes, $I$

Comment: @mathproof: Great! I'll also point out that I've just edited my answer to drop any extra hypothesis of continuity.